# Как вызвать функцию php из js-файла в wordpress?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress

Мне нужно вызвать php функцию с js файла. В functions.php есть функция 
function wp_add_option_payment ($ py_mail) мне надо вызвать ее с script.js который расположен wp-content/themes/theme_name/assets/js. Я пробовал это сделать следующим образом

```
$('#license_pt').blur(
        function() {
            var result = "<?php wp_add_option_payment(); ?>";
        });
```

А вот такое в functions.php

```
function wp_add_option_payment($py_mail){
    global $wpdb;
    add_option('email_who_paid5', $py_mail);
    echo("hello from php");
}
```

UPDATE

Прочитав туториал, я сделал следующим образом.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_unique_action', 'get_offset');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_unique_action', 'get_offset');

function get_offset() {
    echo 'Your ajax request was successful. Here was your offset: <strong>';
  wp_die();
}
```

И в JS

```
$('#pay_bt').click(function() {

        jQuery.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
                type: 'POST',
                action: 'my_unique_action',
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(response) {

                    alert("good");

                },
                error: function(data)
                {
                    alert("Error!" + data);
                }

        });

    });
```

Всегда выбрасывает ошибку и не проходит success в чем проблема? (((

UPDATE2

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myajax_data', 99 );
function myajax_data(){

    wp_localize_script('magicstar-script', 'myajax', 
        array(
            'url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
        )
    );  

}

add_action('wp_footer', 'my_action_javascript', 99); // для фронта

function my_action_javascript() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var data = {
            action: 'my_action',
            whatever: 1234
        };

        // 'ajaxurl' не определена во фронте, поэтому мы добавили её аналог с помощью wp_localize_script()
        $('#pay_bt').click(function() {
            alert("f");
        jQuery.post( myajax.url, data, function(response) {
            alert('Получено с сервера: ' + response);
        });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}

add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback');
function my_action_callback() {
    //$whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );

    echo 10;

    // выход нужен для того, чтобы в ответе не было ничего лишнего, только то что возвращает функция
    wp_die();
}
```

UPDATE 3
Сделал так

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'payment', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/payment.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
```

отдельный файл где

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var data = {
            action: 'my_action',
            whatever: 1234
        };

        $('#pay_bt').click(function() {
            alert("f");
        jQuery.post( myajax.url, data, function(response) {
            alert('Получено с сервера: ' + response);
        });
        });
    });
```

в functions.php оставил

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myajax_data', 99 );
function myajax_data(){

    wp_localize_script('magicstar_scripts', 'myajax', 
        array(
            'url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')
        )
    );  

}

add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback');
function my_action_callback() {
    //$whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );

    echo 10;

    wp_die();
}
```

Comment: Читайте про ajax в WordPress https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html

Comment: А так, как я вызываю не будет работать? Помогите разобраться пожалуйста

Comment: Так не будет. потому что код `wp_add_option_payment();` выполнится при формировании страницы, и переменная result получит фиксированное значение. Читайте то, что я вам показал, разбирайтесь, что такое ajax.

Comment: Прочитав туториал, я сделал следующим образом. add_action('wp_ajax_my_unique_action', 'get_offset');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_unique_action', 'get_offset');

function get_offset() {
//   if( isset($_POST['offset']) ) {
    echo 'Your ajax request was successful. Here was your offset: <strong>';
    // . $_POST['offset'] . '</strong>';
//   }

  wp_die();
}

Comment: И в JS $('#pay_bt').click(function() {

        jQuery.ajax({
       url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
    type: 'POST',
    action: 'my_unique_action',
    // data: {
    // action: 'my_unique_action'
    // },
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(response) {
    
        alert("good");
    
    },
    error: function(data)
                {
                    alert("Error!" + data);
                }
   
  });
    
    }); Всегда выбрасывает ошибку и не проходит success в чем проблема? (((

Comment: Проблема в том, что вы плохо читаете то руководство, на которое я дал ссылку. Где вы там видите php внутри js??? Делайте, как положено, с wp_enqueue_script() и wp_localize_script().

Comment: Можите сказать, что здесь неправильно? Я реально начинающий с PHP и не могу понять, как это реализовать ( wp_localize_script('magicstar-script' 
здесь должно быть название темы?

Comment: Так работать не будет. Скрипт надо не в футере пихать, а запускать функцией wp_enqueue_script ()

Comment: Соответственно, он должен быть в отдельном файле

Comment: Идентификатор скрипта в функциях wp_enqueue_script () и wp_localize_script() должен быть олинаковый

Comment: что вы имели в виду? Идентификатор скрипта в функциях wp_enqueue_script () и wp_localize_script() должен быть олинаковый ? Я изменил UPDATE3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myajax_data' );
function myajax_data(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'payment', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/payment.js', array( 'jquery' ) ); 
    wp_localize_script( 'payment', 'myajax', 
        array(
            'url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        )
    );
}

add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback');
function my_action_callback() {
    $whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );
    echo $whatever;
    wp_die();
}
```

js-файл правильный.

Comment: Большое спасибо!